# How to avoid zero-terminating SQL_BINARY array data when passing it as a parameter? (ODBC Driver)

Tags: c, sql-server, windows, odbc

I just learned the hard way that the **Windows ODBC driver API requires an array of `SQL_BINARY` data, as input parameter, to be terminated with a zero-byte**. Even though I didn't find such a statement in the documentation, I found this out by executing a stored procedure using this code:

**Minimal Example**

```cpp
// Parameter binding
BYTE data[10] = { 15, 3, 54, 144, 34, 211, 200, 147, 15, 74 };
SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_BINARY, 10, 0, data, 0, NULL);

// Procedure execution
SQLRETURN res = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"{call dbo.Update_Data(?)}", SQL_NTS);
```

It caused `SQLExecDirect` to fail with `SQL_NULL_DATA`. Upon querying the Diagnostic Records using `SQLGetDiagRec` I've received the record:

> SQL State = 22001, Error Msg: "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
>   **String or binary data would be truncated**"

While this usually indicates that data being inserted or updated into a column is larger than the column itself, *this isn't the case here*. After 4 hours of trying different parameters and statements I've finally found out the *solution is as simple as terminating the byte array with a zero at the last position*:

```cpp
// Parameter binding
BYTE data[11] = { 15, 3, 54, 144, 34, 211, 200, 147, 15, 74, 0 }; // <- 0 termination here
SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_BINARY, 10, 0, data, 0, NULL);

// Procedure execution
SQLRETURN res = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"{call dbo.Update_Data(?)}", SQL_NTS);
```

**Now I fail to understand why that is so? The function `SQLBindParameter` requires the length of the given data (10 as cbColDef or ColumnSize parameter) and still searches for a zero-byte?**

To my understanding, zero termination is used where the length of an array is not determined by a length indicating variable but the termination of the array with a zero value. This is usually being done with strings. For binary data, that doesn't make much sense to me, as there could be intended zero bytes inside the array before the actual end (determined by a length indicator) is reached. I could possibly run into this issue, so it would be great if **there was some way to avoid zero-terminating the byte array?**

**Full Example**

As requested in the comments here is a full code dump of the unit test:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

// Settings
#define SIP "127.0.0.1"
#define SPort 1433
#define SUID "User"
#define SPW "PW"
#define SDB "world"

// Global ODBC mem
SQLHENV henv;
SQLHDBC hdbc;
SQLHSTMT hstmt;

// Logs Diagnostic records
void ProcessLogs(SQLSMALLINT plm_handle_type, SQLHANDLE &plm_handle);

// The query being tested
void TestQuery()
{
    int col = 0;
    SQLRETURN res = SQL_NTS;

    // Params
    ULONGLONG id = 44;
    BYTE data[10] = { 15, 3, 54, 144, 34, 211, 200, 147, 15, 74 };

    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, ++col, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_UBIGINT, SQL_BIGINT, 0, 0, &id, 0, NULL);
    SQLBindParameter(hstmt, ++col, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_BINARY, 10, 0, data, 0, NULL);

    // Execution
    res = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (UCHAR*)"{call dbo.Update_Store_Data(?,?)}", SQL_NTS);
    if (res != SQL_SUCCESS && res != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        printf("Error during query execution: %hd\n", res);
        ProcessLogs(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
    }
}

// ODBC Driver initialization
bool ODBCInit()
{
    // Init ODBC Handles
    RETCODE res;
    res = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, NULL, &henv);
    res = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_INTEGER);
    res = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);

    // Connection string
    char connStr[512];
    sprintf_s(connStr
        , sizeof(connStr)
        , "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;ADDRESS=%s,%d;NETWORK=DBMSSOCN;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s"
        , SIP
        , SIP
        , SPort
        , SUID
        , SPW
        , SDB);

    // Connection
    char outStr[512];
    SQLSMALLINT pcb;
    res = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)connStr, strlen(connStr), (SQLCHAR*)outStr, ARRAYSIZE(outStr), &pcb, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    if (res != SQL_SUCCESS && res != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        printf("Error during driver connection: %hd\n", res);
        return false;
    }

    // Query handle
    res = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt);

    return true;
}

// ODBC Driver handles cleanup
void ODBCClean()
{
    if (hstmt != SQL_NULL_HSTMT)
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
    if (hstmt != SQL_NULL_HDBC)
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);
    if (hstmt != SQL_NULL_HENV)
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if (ODBCInit())
        TestQuery();
    ODBCClean();

    return 0;
}
```

The SQL Table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Store
(
    UniqueNumber BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ItemID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    AccountUniqueNumber BIGINT NOT NULL,
    StorageType INT NOT NULL,
    Count INT NOT NULL,
    Data BINARY(10) NOT NULL
)
```

The called procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Update_Store_Data
    @ID     BIGINT,
    @Data   BINARY(10)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Store
    SET Data = @Data
    WHERE UniqueNumber = @ID
END
```

Comment: "I just learned the hard way that the Windows ODBC driver API requires an array of SQL_BINARY data, as input parameter, to be terminated with a zero-byte. " - this certainly is not true in my experience. If you believe it to be the case, post some compilable code that demonstrates it and/or report it to the supplier of your ODBC driver as a bug.

Comment: @NeilButterworth You might be lucky and have zero'd memory after binary data that you bind as parameter (happened to me before when it worked). To include the whole ODBC handle allocation and the driver connection would extend this question by at least 50 lines code and would not show a minimal example of the problem anymore imo. I made sure through execution from the management studio directly that the query runs, free of errors. It's definitely a problem with the ODBC driver API.

Comment: I'm not lucky - I have been using and teaching about ODBC for something like 25 years. ODBC is a very complex API and it is very easy to get things wrong. However, it is also very well tested on most platforms, and the assumption should be there is something wrong with your code, not with the API or the  driver.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I mean I'm not trying to question your experience or anything, I've only been dealing with ODBC API on this level for 2 years and this is admittedly my second time I'm using direct binding of arrays. However I've also ran profiling and I've seen it using memory to the point where it found a zero terminating byte in memory garbage, when given enough room. Is there another way of specifying the length of the array to the `SQLBindParameter` function? I don't see where else I could go wrong as the query executes successfully when executed from the management studio.

Comment: Really, without seeing the schema and some compilable code I  don't think I can comment further usefully.  Which is why these are comments, not answers.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've included the full code and SQL table and procedure definition. Please see it below **Full Example**. You should be able to replicate the issue with that. Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Comment: You need to specify [`BufferLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function) to the function, i.e. `SQLBindParameter(..., data, 10, NULL);`

Comment: @putu I have tried that. Sadly it's giving the exact same error, so I reverted that to 0 again.

Comment: If you set the latest param (`StrLen_or_IndPtr`) instead of `NULL` what did you get? It should return the length of binary data, right?

Comment: From the documentation, it almost looks as if `BufferLength` ought to be 1 (the length of a single array element).  As likely as not I'm misinterpreting it, but perhaps it is worth a try. :-)

Comment: @putu If I set that param it leaves the value unchanged. HOWEVER I've tried to set it to 10 before I pass it as `StrLen_or_IndPtr` parameter like: `SQLINTEGER cb = 10; SQLBindParameter(... , &cb);` which has worked! I'm currently trying to reason this further and will write an answer if this has really solved it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yeah the documentation is very contradictory about it. Apparently for my case and the given C-Types and SQL-Types `BufferLength` is completely ignored! Instead I seem to have to pass the buffer length in the `StrLen_or_IndPtr` parameter

Comment: @Vinzenz: As explained below, you have to set both. Buffer length and StrLen_or_IndPtr. And StrLen_or_IndPtr must not always be the same value as buffer length. Think about a VARBINARY column for example..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that binary data must be null-terminated (if that would be true, you could not insert any data containing a 0 value, like `{ 100, 0, 100, 0, 100 }`).

1. You need to set correct values for the **buffer length** (size of the buffer).
2. You need to properly setup and initialize **StrLen_or_IndPtr** argument. For binary buffers, the value of StrLen_or_IndPtr must be the length of the data held in the buffer. Note that this must not be the same as the actual buffer size (but it must be <= buffersize). From the documentation of  [SQLBindParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function):

> The StrLen_or_IndPtr argument points to a buffer that, when SQLExecute
>   or SQLExecDirect is called, contains one of the following [..]:
>
> - The length of the parameter value stored in *ParameterValuePtr. This is  ignored except for character or binary C data.

See below a minimal example that compiles:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqlucode.h>

void printErr(SQLHANDLE handle, SQLSMALLINT handleType)
{
    SQLSMALLINT recNr = 1;
    SQLRETURN ret = SQL_SUCCESS;
    while (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        SQLWCHAR errMsg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH + 1];
        SQLWCHAR sqlState[5 + 1];
        errMsg[0] = 0;
        SQLINTEGER nativeError;
        SQLSMALLINT cb = 0;
        ret = SQLGetDiagRec(handleType, handle, recNr, sqlState, &nativeError, errMsg, SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH + 1, &cb);
        if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        {
            std::wcerr << L"ERROR; native: " << nativeError << L"; state: " << sqlState << L"; msg: " << errMsg << std::endl;
        }
        ++recNr;
    }
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // connect to db
    SQLRETURN   nResult = 0;
    SQLHANDLE   handleEnv = 0;

    nResult = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, (SQLHANDLE*)&handleEnv);
    nResult = SQLSetEnvAttr(handleEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3_80, SQL_IS_INTEGER);

    SQLHANDLE   handleDBC = 0;
    nResult = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, handleEnv, (SQLHANDLE*)&handleDBC);

    SQLWCHAR     strConnect[256] = L"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=.\\TEST;Database=Foobar;Uid=Secret;Pwd=Secret";
    SQLWCHAR     strConnectOut[1024] = { 0 };
    SQLSMALLINT nNumOut = 0;
    nResult = SQLDriverConnect(handleDBC, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)strConnect, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*)strConnectOut, sizeof(strConnectOut), &nNumOut, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleDBC, SQL_HANDLE_DBC);

    // Allocate a statement
    SQLHSTMT    handleStatement = SQL_NULL_HSTMT;
    nResult = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, handleDBC, (SQLHANDLE*)&handleStatement);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleDBC, SQL_HANDLE_DBC);

    int col = 0;
    SQLRETURN res = SQL_NTS;

    // Params
    SQLBIGINT id = 2;
    SQLCHAR data[10] = { 15, 3, 54, 144, 34, 211, 200, 147, 15, 74 };
    SQLLEN cbId = 0;
    SQLLEN cbData = 10;

    res = SQLBindParameter(handleStatement, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_SBIGINT, SQL_BIGINT, 0, 0, &id, sizeof(id), &cbId);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(res))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    res = SQLBindParameter(handleStatement, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_BINARY, 10, 0, data, sizeof(data), &cbData);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(res))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    // Execution
    res = SQLExecDirect(handleStatement, (SQLWCHAR*)L"{call dbo.Update_Store_Data(?,?)}", SQL_NTS);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(res))
    {
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely on spot about the `StrLen_or_IndPtr` argument! I've just adjusted my unit test to set both the `BufferLength` and `StrLen_or_IndPtr` argument to 10 and it worked! Now curious me tested the same thing with leaving `BufferLength` to `0`. And even that worked. So it looks like `BufferLength` is actually being ignored for `SQL_C_BINARY` or related to the `StrLen_or_IndPtr` buffer. Do you get the same result if you leave the `BufferLength` parameter at `0`? If so, can you adjust your answer? Other than that, great answer, thanks for taking the time!!

Comment: It could actually be intended as an if-else system. If the `StrLen_or_IndPtr` parameter is given, it will be interpreted as the length of the binary data. If it is not given (`NULL`) or set to `SQL_NTS` it will try to determine the end of the binary data by zero-termination. This is what I get through testing this, at least. Not sure if it's worth another answer though, maybe you can adjust yours a little? I've accepted it in the meantime

Comment: How buffer-length and StrLen_or_IndPtr are interpeted depends heavily on the SQL C Type used. See the corresponding comments about those arguments in the ODBC API documentation. The answer would become huge if we would like to include all possible combinations.. I would disadvice to not set buffer length: The information is available "for free" with a simple sizeof(). If the driver does not use it - okay, but you are on the safe side if you set it. It could also be very driver specific what a driver does exactly if only one of the arguments are set (null-padding for example)..